# store.load doesn't update gridpanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to load data to tree grid in popup window.
But data is not displaying.
Data comes from server and console.log(store) shows the data but treegrid is empty.
As i understand store loads data but something wrong is in view or model but i can't find the trouble.
Can somebody help me ?

here is opening of popup (it's in controller).
Get store -> add filter -> loadData

```
editCategories: function(grid, record){
        var view = Ext.widget('categorypopup');
        view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
        SelectedCategory.category = record.getId();
        var store = view.down('gridpanel').getStore();
        store.clearFilter(true);
        store.filter([
            {
                property: 'id',
                value: record.getId()
            }
        ]);
        store.load();
    }
```

Here is grid in tab in popup

```
{
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    alias: 'widget.categoryattr',
                    title: 'Attributes',
                    height: 250,
                    cls: 'attributetree',                    
                    buttons: [{'text': 'Add attribute', 'action' : 'add-attribute'}],
                    columns: [
                        {
                            text: 'Id',
                            dataIndex: 'id',
                            width: 50
                        },
                        {
                            dataIndex: 'name',
                            text: 'Name',
                            width: 250
                        }],
                    width: 300,
                    store: attributesStore
                }
```

Here is store for this grid

```
Ext.define('desk.store.CategoryAttributesStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'desk.model.CategoryAttributesModel',
    storeId: 'AttributesStore',
    autoLoad: false,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/admin/get-attributes-by-category/',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',            
            root: 'attributes',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'results'
        }
    }
})
```

Here is the model for the grid

```
Ext.define('desk.model.CategoryAttributesModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'value', type: 'string'}
    ]
})
```

Comment: Does it only happen if the grid tab is inactive, or always?

Comment: In that case, after the store loads, verify that `store.getCount()` returns a number > 0. If the store loads fine, then there is only one reason for that - it is a different store.

Comment: Are you sure that store's instance is ok?

Comment: getCount() returns 0 but i see that the data comes and if i look to console.log(store.data) i can see new elements. I send from php echo json_encode('attributes' => $attrs); so it have to be fine